# How do I evaluate this double-integral?

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

The problem statement is as follows:

Evaluate $\iint xydydx$ over the region bounded by the curves $x = y^2$, $x = 2 - y$, $y = 0$ and $y = 1$.

My confusion is with regards to how the question is to be interpreted. I have tried the following two methods:

1. Plot the curves on the graph and find the coordinates of the points enclosing the region of interest - doing so, I obtained the limits: $x$ goes from 0 to 2 (derived from the plot), $y$ goes from 0 to 1 (as stated in the question). Thus, my integral would look like so:
   $$\int_0^1 \int_{0}^{2}xy dydx$$ and evaluate to 1.

---

2. Treat the integral like so:$$\int_0^1 \int_{y^2}^{2-y}xy dydx$$ in which case, the integral evaluates to: $$\frac 14[4 + y^2 - 4y - y^4]$$

Which of these is the right way to go and how do I identify what is expected of me in solving the question?

[Added a picture of my working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Cvr.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea to draw the region https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7v8tu9svjk

Your second attempt is good 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 y \left( \int_{y^2}^{2-y} x dx \right) dy .
\end{eqnarray*}
Now the inner integral gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{y^2}^{2-y} x dx =  \left[ \frac{x^2}{2} \right]_{y^2}^{2-y}.
\end{eqnarray*}
I will let you complete the problem from here.

Edit : This will give 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_0^1  \frac{y}{2} \left[ 4-4y+y^2-y^4 \right]dy
\end{eqnarray*}
& Don Antonio's value $\color{red}{\frac{3}{8}}$ agrees with Wolfram alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1(+int_%7By%5E2%7D%5E%7B2-y%7D+x+y+dx)+dy and the value I have calculated in my notebook.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did complete the integration further and ended up with $\frac 14[4 + y^2 - 4y - y^4]$. Is that correct? I'm confused between this and DonAntonio's answer.

Comment: Right. I understood that you're calculating $x.dx$ as the inner integral first, and with respect to $y$ after that. In my working, I was calculating $y.dy$ as the inner integral. Should that even make a difference? I've added a photo of my working for your perusal. Thanks!

Edit: Whoops, I think I caught my mistake. I should be integrating w.r.t x first, shouldn't I?

Comment: You must do the $x$ integration first, the $y$ integration depends on the outcome of this! ... & besides, you would not expect the answer to be a function of $y$.

Comment: Finally clicked, I guess! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You are welcome $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 1):

Do a drawing of the horizontal parabola and the straight lines. We have:

$$\int_0^1\int_{y^2}^1xy\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy+\int_1^2\int_0^{2-x}xy\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\frac12\int_0^1y(1-y^4)\,dy+\frac12\int_1^2x\left((2-x)^2-0^2\right)\,dx$$

$$=\frac14-\frac1{12}+\frac12\int_1^2\left(4x-4x^2+x^3\right)\,dx=\frac16+\frac12\left(2(4-1)-\frac43(8-1)+\frac14(16-1)\right)=$$

$$=\frac16+3-\frac{28}6+\frac{15}8=\frac{4+72-112+45}{24}=\frac9{24}=\frac38$$

Observe that your integration domain is *irregular* and thus we had to split it into two regular regions...Check the arithmetic above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm slightly confused here though. In Donald's answer above, they indicated that my second attempt was the way forward, in which case, my answer would be a function of $y$ as I mentioned in the question. Could you please explain why we had to 'split' the integral and proceed that way, and if we end up with the same answer if we go by Donald's answer? Thanks!

Comment: I just tried to do splitting the domain, which is the same shown in the above answer. Check it and I shall check it further

Comment: Thank you @DonAntonio, once again. Your answer and Donald's answer above both helped me correct the error and I think I now understand where I was erring.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\ds{\iint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{2}}xy\bracks{x > 0}\bracks{y > 0}
\bracks{y < 2 - x}\bracks{y < \root{x}}\dd x\,\dd y}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}y\int_{0}^{\infty}x\bracks{y^{2} < x < 2 - y}\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}y\bracks{y^{2} < 2 - y}\int_{y^{\large 2}}^{2 - y}x\,\dd x\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{\infty}y\bracks{-2 < y < 1}
\pars{2 - 2y + {1 \over 2}\,y^{2} - {1 \over 2}\,y^{4}}\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{2y - 2y^{2} + {1 \over 2}\,y^{3} - {1 \over 2}\,y^{5}}\dd y = 1 - {2 \over 3} + {1 \over 8} - {1 \over 12} =
\bbx{3 \over 8} = 0.375
\end{align}

> $\ds{\bracks{\cdots}}$ is an *Iverson Bracket* which is very helpful to handle constraints: $\ds{\bracks{P} = \color{red}{1}}$ whenever $\ds{P}$ is *true* and $\ds{\color{red}{0}}$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is something new to me!